# Can I tell VSCode to recognize a different escape character under specific circumstances (Windows Dockerfiles)?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, dockerfile

When using Visual Studio Code to edit Windows Dockerfiles which include the `` # escape=` ``  statement, the escape character is the backtick, and not the backslash. This makes for awkward code-reading, especially when dealing with Windows file paths that involve backslashes. I generally use forward slashes for my file paths in Powershell in part for this reason, but there are still a few corner cases (for example, the IIS "webadministration" module, or the path to the binary for a Windows service) where backslashes are still required in file paths in order for Windows to function correctly. This is often compounded in Windows Dockerfiles, and results in odd looking stretches of code in which it appears that long strings are improperly quoted or escaped. Consider the following basic Windows Dockerfile:

```docker
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

ARG serviceName

ARG serviceDisplayName

ARG serviceBinary

# create a Windows service
RUN powershell -Command `
  New-Service -Name $env:serviceName `
    -BinaryPathName ('C:\' + $env:serviceName + '\' + $env:serviceBinary) `
    -DisplayName $env:serviceDisplayName `
    -StartupType Auto; `
  # there is still no Powershell native way to manage the recovery options of a service, so we use sc.exe
  & sc.exe failure $env:serviceName reset= 0 actions= restart/60000
```

Because of this quirk, everything after `-BinaryPathName` will be *displayed* as incorrectly escaped, but function as intended. I think it also has something to do with single quotes vs. double quotes, where we have to use single quotes in Windows Dockerfiles, because Dockerfiles do not reliably pass double quotes on to Powershell and result in incorrectly formed strings and commands and [require cantankerous escape sequences to be used correctly](https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/tree/789fa0b54c0d0263fa9464025cfe12ec2fe0cd6c/quotes).

Is it possible to instruct VSCode to recognize the backtick as the escape character specifically when editing a Windows Dockerfile? I know that it can recognize the difference when editing Powershell files, so the behavior is technically possible. I cloned the repo for the Powershell extension for VSCode and I am examining it in hopes I can perhaps create a modification to the Dockerfile extension on my own, but so far I have not been able to figure out the relevant portion of the code.

Edit: addressing [postanote's answer regarding splatting as a potential formatting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67679850/1188629), unfortunately the answer is no. I tried splatting the variables into a hash and the same formatting problem occurs right after the first use of a single backslash and continues for the remainder of the text:

```docker
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

ARG serviceName

ARG serviceDisplayName

ARG serviceBinary

# create a Windows service
RUN powershell -Command `                                              # formatting problem starts here
  $splatMyService = @{ Name = $env:Servicename; BinaryPathName = ('C:\' + $env:serviceName + '\' + $env:serviceBinary); `
    DisplayName = $env:serviceDisplayName; StartupType = 'Auto' } `
  New-Service @splatMyService `
  & sc.exe failure $env:serviceName reset= 0 actions= restart/60000
```

Comment: Are you saying, [PowerShell Spatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting), is not a workable option for you for readability?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

***Full disclosure, I don't use docker***, so the below has not been validated, but have you tried/considered the below approaches?

[about_Splatting | MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=%20About%20Splatting%20%201%20Short%20description.%20Describes,the%20array...%204%20See%20also.%20%20More%20)

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
ARG serviceName
ARG serviceDisplayName
ARG serviceBinary

$NewServiceSplat = @{
    Name           = $env:serviceName
    BinaryPathName = "C:\$($env:serviceName)\$env:serviceBinary"
    DisplayName    = $env:serviceDisplayName
    StartupType    = 'Auto'
}
RUN powershell -Command New-Service @NewServiceSplat

& sc.exe failure $env:serviceName reset= 0 actions= restart/60000
```

Or this way...

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

```
# 5. The Call Operator &

& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi" /fullscreen

<#
Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters or there are spaces in the arguments or paths!

With spaces you have to nest Quotation marks and the result it is not always clear! 

In this case it is better to separate everything like so:
#>

$CMD  = 'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 = 'filename1'
$arg2 = '-someswitch'
$arg3 = 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 = '-yetanotherswitch'

& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4

# or same like that:
$AllArgs = @(
    'filename1', 
    '-someswitch', 
    'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', 
    '-yetanotherswitch'
)
& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion; I'm not sure, I'll try it. I think the answer is no, in that spatting is still going to result in the backslashes being in-line in the code in such a way that it will be interpreted as escape sequences. But it's definitely worth trying. I always forget about splatting, and it's such a nice way to tidy things up.

Comment: Unfortunately no, that does not work. I've updated the question to reflect this. Thanks for taking a stab at it :-)